# How do I fix "java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "16.0dip""

Tags: android, android-debug

I'm parsing data from my BooksAdapter to BookDetailActivity and I am getting a `NumberFormatException: Invalid float: 16.0dip` error in my logcat.

I have searched the error online but I got only 3 search results which haven't been helpful.

```
'BookDetailActivity'
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_book_detail);

    Book book = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Book");
}

'BooksAdapter'
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        Book selectedBook = books.get(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), BookDetail.class);
        intent.putExtra("Book", selectedBook);
        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
```

I expected the BookDetailActivity to be launched after the user clicks on an item from the RecyclerView. Instead, the app crashes.

```
(java;no:11 from logcat) = setContentView(R.layout.activity_book_detail);
```

Error from log cat is:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{www.frank.books/www.frank.books.BookDetail}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "16.0dip"
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1280)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1096)
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "16.0dip"
>           at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
>           at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:310)
>           at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:300)
>           at android.content.res.TypedArray.getFloat(TypedArray.java:300)
>           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams.(ConstraintLayout.java:2822)
>           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.generateLayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.java:1972)
>           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.generateLayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.java:482)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:770)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>           at www.frank.books.BookDetail.onCreate(BookDetail.java:11)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1280) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1096) 
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZoCS.png


book_detail.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BookDetail">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgCover"
        android:layout_width="163dp"
        android:layout_height="184dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard_margin"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAuthors"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/book_open"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/standard_margin"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/standard_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/standard_margin"
        android:text="@string/tv_title"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAuthors"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/standard_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/standard_margin"
        android:text="@string/tv_subtitle"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTitle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_authors"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/standard_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard_margin"
        android:text="@string/tv_author"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgCover"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAuthors" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPublisher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/standard_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard_margin"
        android:text="@string/tv_publisher"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgCover"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_authors" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPublishedDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/standard_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard_margin"
        android:text="@string/tv_pub_date"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgCover"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvPublisher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/standard_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/standard_margin"
        android:text="@string/tv_detail"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="@dimen/standard_margin"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgCover" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

dimens.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="title_size">20sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="authors_size">18sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="published_date_padding">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="standard_margin">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Comment: Can you please post you activity_book_detail.xml file code

Comment: It seems that in your layout xml, you are using some values, which should be float, but you have given it as 16.0dip ... Please check the values.

Comment: @yash786 Check it out. I've posted it.

Comment: At least u can use `try..catch` statement + printStackTrace() method to stop crushing. In my cases, this helps me to understand the solution much faster.

Comment: And I want to ask another one question: Maybe you fill some field with dimens in design tab if you use Android Studio ?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this route:
`at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)` which says the class `StringToReal` at line 63 has a problem.

I think you have casted a string with value of `16.0dp` to float which is invalid.

First clear the `dp` of it using something like:

```
String a = "16.0dp";
Strign newA = a.replace("dp", "");
```

and then try to cast it.

But since this is not your source to change, you should check where you have given output to this. check your `dimens.xml` and see where you have used invalid values.

Comment: I can't find any value with 16.0dp. Where can I find the StringToReal class?

Comment: Can you share your `dimens.xml` as well?

Comment: I have shared it below the book_detail.xml